# How to filter for a content type Id when getting sharepoint items using the graph api?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, odata, sharepoint-online

I would like to get all items from a SharePoint list, which have a specific content type.

So far I have tried

- lists/{myList}/items?$filter=contentType/id eq '{myCTId}'
- lists/{myList}/items?$filter=contentType/name eq '{myCTName}'
- lists/{myList}/items?$filter=startswith(contentType/name, '{myCTName}')

None of the above seem to work for me, all resulting in a general error.

```
"code": "generalException",
    "message": "An unspecified error has occurred.",
```

Does anyone have an idea/ suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: As of now filter is not supported on the `lists/{listid}/items` endpoint and there is already a uservoice raised [here](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/38989819-sharepoint-listitem-filter-support-on-fields). Please upvote it so that this feature could be developed in the future. As a work around you can filter it on your end(writing code).

Comment: Moving this to answer.

Answer (score 1):

As of now filter is not supported on the `lists/{listid}/items` endpoint and there is already a uservoice raised [here](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/38989819-sharepoint-listitem-filter-support-on-fields). Please upvote it so that this feature could be developed in the future. As a work around you can filter it on your end(writing code).

Comment: The link is dead "Site deactivated"

Comment: Looks like the website is down.

Comment: It is perma down apparently

Comment: MS Graph uservoice was closed down, please support this new request: https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/aa3cdd9a-b9f3-ec11-a81b-000d3a00c008